# Can you propagate custom data in New Activity?

Tags: activities

Is there a way to propagate the "With Contacts" address and phone number into the activities assignee's copy email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the code correctly, it sends the slightly misnamed "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity" template, found under **Mailings menu > Message Templates**, "System Workflow Messages" tab.

If you add a Smarty debug tab, like this: `{debug}` to the top of the template, you should be able to send yourself a message and see a list of all available variables, which you can add as Smarty tags.  If what you're looking for isn't there (I suspect it's not), you can add it.  The core code is here: `CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php`.  You'd be better off using an extension that adds them as part of hook_buildForm though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Jon. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Jon, I'm still learning here and will build an extension later. When adding a field to Activity.php. How do you propagate the entity's address; 

),
      'assignee_contact_address' => array(
        'type' => 'entityRef', <-------Something here?
        'label' => ts('Contacts Address'),
        'attributes' => array(
          'multiple' => TRUE,
          'create' => TRUE,
          'api' => array('params' => array('is_deceased' => 0)),
        ),

Comment: When selecting 'entityRef', instead the name being filled In, it should fill in the address.

Comment: Sean - that seems like it belongs in its own question, both because the formatting is unreadable and because it will never get found by others here.

Comment: ok, I will re-post it